# Show validation errors in a list instead below each input

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I'm using a custom form template and all is working at least the error list, follow the template:

```
'errorList' => '<ul>{{content}}</ul>',
'errorItem' => '<li>{{text}}</li>',
'input' => '<input {{type}} {{attrs}} {{name}} class="form-control">',
```

When some validation error happens, I'm getting the errors displayed below each input. I need to do something more to show the errors in a list ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happens exactly since you are not providing the rest of the code, but so far i can see an error in  closing tag

```
'errorList' => '<ul>{{content}}</li>',
```

maybe that's the problem

```
'errorList' => '<ul>{{content}}</ul>',
```

Comment: thanks, but thats not the problem... the rest of code is normal.. on controller I'm saving the data, if theres any error the app back to form and provide the errors each one inside each input

Comment: You need to include the rest of your code -> Best way todo so is using a http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: The code is a regular pattern. form created with form helper, controller generated with cake.